# ( Sprintf ) pros and cons, embedded design

Tags: microcontroller, c, embedded

What are the negatives aspects of using sprintf in embedded environments? I'd like to hear opinions and/or experiences on this.

I have heard and read people recommending avoiding the constant use of sprintf for data formatting, or appending strings.

I personally have performed a couple of experiments to measure its performance in terms of execution time, compared to my own function to format a given string for example. But I found no significant difference at all.

Could someone please clearly explain what are its disadvantages?

Comment: What do the people who recommend avoiding `sprintf` suggest as the alternative ? Their suggestion might be specific to a particular implementation or platform.

Comment: Embedded programmers as old as I am probably remember the days when using any of the standard printf functions would eat up half the code space in the micro, and the majority of the functionality provided by printf would end up unused. These days though, the space available for code has increased by orders of magnitude so the 'cost' of using printf has effectively decreased - so the time saved by using it (over rolling your own custom string formatter) ends up being more important.

Comment: ... and on a side note, *please* use s**n**printf in your code rather than sprintf. Buffer overruns can cost you hours or even days of debugging time ...

Comment: printf flavors still rely on a massive amount of library support, soft/hard fpu support, etc.  very rarely is it worth that cost.  why increase the cost of the part and cut into profits when you dont have to.   and use snprintf and other length limited functions.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that "printf" is a moving target. That is, the implementation of the printf family of functions depends on your library. So it may be that modern C libraries designed for embedded settings have much more efficient printf than what used to be typical. (In cases where the cost of printf is too high, your own hand-rolled string-formatting functions may also be too expensive! But it might be that in your application, performance is not critical enough for this to be a problem.)

Answer (score 4):

I use sprintf() all the time in embedded programming and even real time applications to format data items into packets for communications links that use human readable data representations.  The only limitations that I have found are as follows:

1. Some embedded implementations are very code memory size constrained and the addition of standard library code to support the the printf/sprintf functions can add a good bit to the size of the executable code. This constraint has largely been eliminated in most of the modern embedded environments that use 32-bit processors. Some of these processors have code memory on board in the megabytes. Twenty years ago when 8-bit MCUs with just a few K-bytes of code memory were the mainstream of embedded programming this was a much bigger deal.
2. Processor operating frequency will have a big impact on the amount of time to execute the sprintf code and its underlying conversion routines. Similar to the above item the common 32-bit MCUs in use often are operating at 100 to 200MHz and more. Even in tight realtime applications the more efficient instruction sets on these MCUs make the conversion routines run very fast compared to something like an old 8-bit 8051 MCU running at 20MHz or less.
3. Do not be trying to format strings inside of interrupt service routines.

Comment: Please tell me that sprintf is a typo and you actually use snprintf ;)

Comment: On that point 3. What is reason behind avoiding sprintf inside interrupt service routines ? Is it the execution time itself of this routine, probably too long or any particular reasons for this ? Thanks for the good answers 

Comment: @FelAn - Putting long executing routines inside ISRs is just plain a bad practice. One day when you do this and then spend a week or more debugging a strange and complex bug related to interrupts, concurrency, global variables you will always thereafter keep your ISRs as simple, short and orderly as possible.

Comment: @brhans - I use the term sprintf in this answer in a generic sense since that is what was asked in the question. Keep in mind that it can be perfectly safe to use sprintf with proper coding. A key issue is to always specify the x.y field size specification.